# Tabla pivot con 3 modelos en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo 3 tablas: Draw, jugador y ronda, y a su vez una tabla en común para las tres teniendo como atributos: id, id_draw, id_jugador, id_ronda.

Lo que no se, es como armar este tipo de relaciones y como insertar datos. Ya que en una relación mucho a muchos con dos tablas seria: draw->jugador()->atach(...);

Con este tipo de relación de 3 tablas nose como hacer para insertar datos y armar la relación belongsToMany.

Relaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La relacion ternaria esta dada por draw - JugadorATP - Ronda siendo la tabla resultante Partidos

Comment: No tienes ternaria realmente, es simplemente una entidad más, por lo que tendrás un modelo para Partido. ¿Qué datos son los que quieres insertar y no sabes cómo?

Comment: Lo arregle de realizando: 

$draw->jugadoresatp()->attach($idJugadorATP, ['id_ronda' => $id_ronda, 'posicion' => $posicion ]);

Como idDraw, idJugadorATP y idRonda son 3 claves primarias y a la vez 3 FK. Pense que habia una forma de insertar los 3 datos a la vez, pero creo que la solucion anterior funciona!

Comment: Ese puede ser un modo de hacerlo, sí. Aunque no sé si más adelante vas a tener algun otro problema con las relaciones. Personalmente crearia un modelo para la tabla partidos para manejarlo más facilmente. Puedes permitirte un modelo siempre que tengas una clave autoincremental, como está pasando en Partidos. No podrías si la clave primaria fuera compuesta por `idDraw`, `idJugadorATP` e `idRonda`, por lo que comentaba en mi respuesta de que Eloquent no tiene soporte para claves compuestas, que no tiene relación directa con que puedas crearlas en las migraciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que **Eloquent no tiene soporte para claves primarias compuestas**, te recomiendo que plantees la estructura de tu base de datos de una forma distinta para ahorrarte dolores de cabeza.

Suponiendo (no sé si será así, pero se puede adaptar) que una ronda tiene varias tiradas (draws) y una tirada pertenece a un jugador, puedes montar unas relaciones:

*jugador 1 - N draw* (jugador **hasMany** draws, draw **belongsTo** jugador)

*ronda 1 - N draw* (ronda **hasMany** draws, draw **belongsTo** ronda)

Proporciona más información acerca de las relaciones que deseas realizar para que te pueda mostrar un ejemplo más complejo.

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

> Es tenis... - un Draw(Cuadro de tenis) tiene muchos jugadores y muchas rondas. - Un jugador va estar en muchos draws y muchas rondas. - Una ronda va estar en muchos draws y va tener muchos jugadores.

*draw M - N jugador* (jugador **belongsToMany** draw, draw **belongsToMany** jugador)

*draw M - N ronda* (draw **belongsToMany** ronda, ronda **belongsToMany** draw)

*jugador M - N ronda* (jugador **belongsToMany** ronda, ronda **belongsToMany** jugador)

Ahí tienes tres relaciones con tabla pivote entre ellas, pero hace falta más información, ya que estas usando una ternaria pero no has proporcionado suficientes detalles para saber qué intentas hacer.

Comment: Es tenis... 
- un Draw(Cuadro de tenis) tiene muchos jugadores y muchas rondas. 
- Un jugador va estar en muchos draws y muchas rondas.
- Una ronda va estar en muchos draws y va tener muchos jugadores.

Comment: @JuanPabloB No termino de entender el concepto de draw, por lo que no puedo poner unas relaciones que sepa seguro que van a servir en este caso. ¿Qué hace que requieras de una ternaria? Proporciona todos los detalles necesarios para poder construir un modelo relacional preciso.

Comment: Ahí modifique mi post subiendo la parte del UML que interesa. Cualquier duda de la relación pregunta. @GerardReches