# Laravel / Consulta Eloquent entre tablas no relacionadas (Muchos a muchos)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Mi problema es que tengo una relación de muchos a muchos entre la tabla *subject* y *teacher*, por lo tanto, tengo tabla detalle o intermedia ( *teacherSubject* ).

Debo mostrar en la plantilla blade (vista) de *Teacher* las *subject* que se encuentren relacionadas a ese *teacher*, cómo ven no puedo usar join porque directamente las tablas de *subject* y *teacher* no están relacionadas ya que los ID son recuperados en la tabla detalle.

Traté de usar la tabla intermedia para tal fin pero no tengo una idea específica de cómo llamar el atributo.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31678/tabla-pivot-con-3-modelos-en-laravel

Comment: oye, que pena, yo sé que tienes mucha más experiencia en este sitio que yo, pero si puedes ver soy nueva. Gracias por la ayuda, pero podrís ayudarme más si no tuviera un negativo. Mi pregunta es totalmente valida, si me respondieras con un _Mira esa pregunta ya esta resuelta, busca aqui_ o me explicaras que debo hacer, entonces entendería y progresaría. Solo es un saludo, no había necesidad de eliminarlo.

Comment: te saludo y te comento lo siguiente tu pregunta es valida solo que ese punto que edité esta de mas; te aconsejo leer el siguiente enlace para que enriquezcas tu pregunta y sea mejor recibida por la comunidad; ya que se espera que sea la duda que tienes y una muestra del código intentado al momento https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

En modelo subject

```
 public function teachers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teacher','teacherSubject ','id_subject','id_teacher');
    }
```

En modelo teacher

```
public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject','teacherSubject ','id_subject','id_teacher');
    }
```

Comment: wow, gracias.. lo probaré y te diré si funciona..

Comment: PD: también puedes usar Subject::class en lugar de  'App\Subject'

Comment: si, gracias.. por lo general lo uso asi. Otra situación, si no es problema: Como muestro la información que necesito mostrar?